# Politics in implementing a belief for a project

Tags: professionalism, project-management, politics

I have been hired by a phone company to implement Google Analytics for their Android device. With my skills in Google Infrastructure, I can help them create apps using Google products.

My goal is to send all voice commands and actions in a Siri-like voice application in the company to Google Analytics. Within 1 week, I made it work and know the next steps. However, when I ask management about what they want me to track, the priorities were not set. I also somewhat detected through their intentions of using Google Analytics that the application has huge limitations not intended for their goal of counting all phones around the world with certain complicated reasons why it will not work. However, I did not know how to tell them why because I had a 10 month project in my hands, and I wanted to discover the general scope of the project so I could implement it correctly.

I technically finished the project within 3 weeks of both learning Android, and learning to save through their unified project repository.

Then my primary boss's mother died and applied for a 2 week leave. Without my boss's help in leading me to which priorities or path should the project lead, I needed to identify the project on my own by asking questions to whoever could give me answers.

However, there was also tension between another lady programmer who created an Analytics program for the company (not connected to Google Analytics). She limits me in touching her code, and made me perform less by means of diverting me to some other unnecessary tasks like measuring packets (which I already told them that it was more or less 2KB to 3KB). It did not lead anywhere but oblivion for 2 weeks of measuring unnecessary data. I just proved that Google Analytics packet size was sending 1KB each action sent.

My secondary boss seems to feel like I was asking too much questions, and thought that I did not know what I was doing.

I could already sense that letting me measure packets was a trap. If I fight against them, my next actions would not lead anywhere, they would tell me that I'm not doing the priorities they assigned. So I decided to stick to whatever they told me to do (despite the contradiction within me that tells me to fight for the project I believe in), instead of fighting for what I think could have been right.

My boss came back after a 2 week leave from her mother's burial, and my senses did not fail me. I got fired and told that I am not doing the priorities I meant to do.

During the exit interview, I asked them if they could point out the priorities that I should have done for Google Analytics. Because they can not identify the priorities, I explained to them that I was trying to help them identify the priorities by means of explaining how Google Analytics work.

Basically, I was in bad luck.

**Question:** If it were you on my shoes, wherein you believe in the project, would you fight for it? How would you use influence in manipulating the situation to solve the issue?

Comment: Hey Bandage, and welcome to [workplace.se]. As explained in our [help/dont-ask], *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."* Without a concrete problem that actually has a solution, there is no good way to answer. If you can find a way to make your question meet the guidelines in our [help/on-topic], please [edit] and you will get better answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem seems practical because the story represent an actuality of doing something about a project. It is answerable (although it may not show concreteness as to "yes" or "no", but an explanation of "how to do it the next time around" ), and the question shows actual problem that I face. Thanks for letting me explain.

Comment: The question also belong to the following criteria: (1) inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
(2)tend to have long, not short, answers
have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
(3)invite sharing experiences over opinions
(4)insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
(5)are more than just mindless social fun. I do not honestly know if there is an answer to this. If I know the answer, I would have not asked.

Comment: Bandage, if you think my comment is incorrect, please feel free to [ask a question on meta](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to discuss it. I've been wrong in the past, and am happy to discuss it in a meta question if you would like.

Comment: I'm not fighting for the previous project. I wanted to learn from it, wherein I can study, apply, and solve the situation in context. If the situation in context happens again, and it seems clear enough in connection to this problem, the chance of implementing the correct behavior, or manipulating the behavior that affects the situation could give me the correct answers (psychologically and sociologically speaking).

Answer (score 4):

> Question: If it were you on my shoes, wherein you believe in the
>   project, would you fight for it? How?

I would not fight, but i would leave and move on. When trust is lost, everything is lost. **They lost their trust in you.**

I know your heart might be beating to throw yourself in the middle and say your part of story to correct them, especially if you know for a fact that they're wrong and you're right. **But......**

once some one has made up their mind you cant change their mind. the only thing you can do is say "oh well too bad".

Before you fight for something, ask these questions to yourself:

1. Is it worth my time?
2. What am I fighting for, and how is it connected to my life?
3. If you could do all over again, would you change anything?

Go have a beer my friend, you are worth more than what they have measured/thought. I sincerely appreciate your efforts in the project, sometimes it goes unnoticed because of pure politics.

I didn’t see it then, but it turned out that getting fired from Apple was the best thing that could have ever happened to me. The heaviness of being successful was replaced by the lightness of being a beginner again, less sure about everything. It freed me to enter one of the most creative periods of my life. - **Steve Jobs**

" There is a reason why things happen, there is always a good reason behind it"

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Nope, I can feel and sense. I was sometime back in the same situation as the OP.

Comment: I just wanted to add that I do not really want to correct them because I know that I can not change their mind. I'm just thinking if there are ways to solve the problem, what will it be? Could it be on social interactions or communication? For me, this seems to have sociological answers, because psychology may lead to the wrong path of just accepting what was on the plate. Accepting defeat is one thing. Now, what's the best thing to do to solve the issue so it would not lead to this problem?